# How to scan a file for keywords?

Tags: python

So I was bored and my friend suggest I should code an anti cheat because I couldn't come up with what to code myself. It's supposed to dump the history of the web browser then search it through using keywords. So when a user is under investigation instead of them having to screenshare and click through every file and manually check the browser history this would automate that task. Anyways here's the code I've made so far.

```
from browser_history import get_history

output = get_history()
his = output.histories

outputfile = open("demo.txt", "w")
print(his, file= outputfile)
outputfile.close()

with open('demo.txt') as f:
    if "hack" in f.read():
        print("True")
```

It works but I also want it to read keywords out of a file and then print those keywords if they have been found. So for example if the user has searched for example "minecraft cheat" or something like that then it would print that it has found a search for "minecraft cheat".

I'm sorry if its a dumb question but I have spent quite a while looking and I can't really find any good tutorial on it. Also I was just doing some testing now and for some reason it doesnt print any of the history from today only yesterday. So if anyone knows of any good way to get the history I'd love to hear suggestions on how to improve the code.

Comment: You're adding a number of steps by writing histories to file, then loading it back in again.  `his` is already a list you could search.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make a small change in how you read from the file:

```
from browser_history import get_history

output = get_history()
his = output.histories

with open("demo.txt", "w") as f: 
   f.write(his)

with open("demo.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if "hack" in line: 
            print("True")
```

But since 'his' is already a list, you could read directly from it instead of storing it in a file first, but it's up to you!

Answer (score 0):

I never heard of the browser-history library before, pretty neat idea and you could have a lot of fun with this project making gradual improvements to your program. Enjoy!

A small addition to the above answer as I think you were suggesting you wanted to search for multiple keywords and print the keyword found rather than just "True". You could iterate over a list of keywords for each line as follows:

```
from browser_history import get_history

output = get_history()
his = output.histories

outputfile = open("demo.txt", "w")
print(his, file=outputfile)
outputfile.close()

keywords = ['hack', 'minecraft cheat', 'i love cheating']

with open("demo.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        for keyword in keywords:
            if keyword in line:
                print(keyword, "found")
```

It is important that the `keyword` loop is inside the `line` loop here because there are lots of lines so you don't want to iterate over them several times.

By the way I had a look at the `browser-history` documentation but couldn't work out why it doesn't return all history. For me it is returning back as far as 27th December but my actual browser history goes back much further. Good luck getting to the bottom of that.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help im still trying to get to the bottom of this mystery tho. Now it detects the string hack but not minecraft cheat or anything else for some reason. I will have to do some testing and try to see why that may be and im coding in a linux vm so i dont know if that might have anything to do with it. But ill continue trying this out. Actually might have found a partial bit of the problem, it prints the url so in the url it would be minecraft+hack instead of minecraft hack.

Comment: The "+" will almost certainly explain it. You can of course change the keywords, you might also want to look into regular expressions to perform smarter searches. For example the regular expression `/minecraft\W*cheat/` would match any kind of punctuation between the two words, as you can see here: https://regex101.com/r/slh0Ms/1